# Error uploading image using node.js - Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Im testing examples of Express but i have problems with this one.

I'm trying to execute this code example (example taken from the web) and i having this error when i try to upload an image.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'file' of undefined
```

SERVER

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require("fs");

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer  = require('multer');

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
var multer = require('multer');

app.get('/index.html', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile( __dirname + "/" + "index.html" );
})

app.post('/file_upload', function (req, res) {
   console.log(req.files.file.name);
   console.log(req.files.file.path);
   console.log(req.files.file.type);
   var file = __dirname + "/" + req.files.file.name;

   fs.readFile( req.files.file.path, function (err, data) {
      fs.writeFile(file, data, function (err) {
         if( err ){
            console.log( err );
            }else{
               response = {
                  message:'File uploaded successfully',
                  filename:req.files.file.name
               };
            }
         console.log( response );
         res.end( JSON.stringify( response ) );
      });
   });
})

var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
   var host = server.address().address
   var port = server.address().port

   console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
})
```

CLIENT

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>File Uploading Form</title>
   </head>

   <body>
      <h3>File Upload:</h3>
      Select a file to upload: <br />

      <form action = "http://127.0.0.1:8081/file_upload" method = "POST" 
         enctype = "multipart/form-data">
         <input type="file" name="file" size="50" />
         <br />
         <input type = "submit" value = "Upload File" />
      </form>

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's almost certainly this line: `var file = __dirname + "/" + req.files.file.name;` Make sure `req.files.file` is correct.

Comment: You said you're "testing examples" but what is the source of said examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>File Upload</title>
 </head>

<body>
  <h3>File Upload:</h3>
  Select a file to upload: <br />

  <form action = "http://127.0.0.1:8081/file_upload" method = "POST" 
     enctype = "multipart/form-data">
     <input type="file" name="foo" size="50" />
     <br />
     <input type = "submit" value = "Upload File" />
  </form>

 </body>
</html>
```

Server.js

```
 var express = require('express');
 var app = express();
 var path = require("path");
 var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
 var multer  = require('multer');
 app.use(express.static('public'));
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

 app.get('/index.html', function (req, res) {
 res.sendFile( __dirname + "/" + "index.html" );
 })

 var upload = multer({
  dest: path.join(__dirname, '../public/upload/temp')
 });


 app.post('/file_upload', upload.single('foo'), function(req, res) {
  if (req.file) {
  console.dir(req.file);
  return res.end('Uploaded successfuly');
 }
 res.end('No file found');
 });

 var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
   var host = server.address().address
   var port = server.address().port

   console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
 })
```

For multi upload change upload.single('foo') to upload.array('foo')